# Thymeleaf warnings

Tags: karate

Any other karate users getting constant thymeleaf warnings in the logs? It's a mild pain sorting for valid info among them. Curious if an issue being submitted on Github is warranted.

```
10:45:44.828 [pool-2-thread-1] WARN  o.t.s.p.AbstractStandardFragmentInsertionTagProcessor - [THYMELEAF][pool-2-thread-1][karate-feature.html] Deprecated unwrapped fragment expression "karate-posthog.html" found in template karate-feature.html, line 15, col 15. Please use the complete syntax of fragment expressions instead ("~{karate-posthog.html}"). The old, unwrapped syntax for fragment expressions will be removed in future versions of Thymeleaf.
10:45:44.832 [pool-2-thread-1] WARN  o.t.s.p.AbstractStandardFragmentInsertionTagProcessor - [THYMELEAF][pool-2-thread-1][karate-feature.html] Deprecated unwrapped fragment expression "karate-leftnav.html" found in template karate-feature.html, line 31, col 14. Please use the complete syntax of fragment expressions instead ("~{karate-leftnav.html}"). The old, unwrapped syntax for fragment expressions will be removed in future versions of Thymeleaf.
10:45:44.836 [pool-2-thread-1] WARN  o.t.s.p.StandardIncludeTagProcessor - [THYMELEAF][pool-2-thread-1][karate-feature.html] Deprecated attribute {th:include,data-th-include} found in template karate-feature.html, line 74, col 16. Please use {th:insert,data-th-insert} instead, this deprecated attribute will be removed in future versions of Thymeleaf.
10:45:44.837 [pool-2-thread-1] WARN  o.t.s.p.AbstractStandardFragmentInsertionTagProcessor - [THYMELEAF][pool-2-thread-1][karate-feature.html] Deprecated unwrapped fragment expression "karate-step.html" found in template karate-feature.html, line 74, col 16. Please use the complete syntax of fragment expressions instead ("~{karate-step.html}"). The old, unwrapped syntax for fragment expressions will be removed in future versions of Thymeleaf.
10:45:44.869 [pool-2-thread-1] WARN  o.t.s.p.StandardIncludeTagProcessor - [THYMELEAF][pool-2-thread-1][karate-feature.html] Deprecated attribute {th:include,data-th-include} found in template karate-feature.html, line 74, col 16. Please use {th:insert,data-th-insert} instead, this deprecated attribute will be removed in future versions of Thymeleaf.
10:45:44.869 [pool-2-thread-1] WARN  o.t.s.p.AbstractStandardFragmentInsertionTagProcessor - [THYMELEAF][pool-2-thread-1][karate-feature.html] Deprecated unwrapped fragment expression "karate-step.html" found in template karate-feature.html, line 74, col 16. Please use the complete syntax of fragment expressions instead ("~{karate-step.html}"). The old, unwrapped syntax for fragment expressions will be removed in future versions of Thymeleaf.
10:45:44.890 [pool-2-thread-1] WARN  o.t.s.p.StandardIncludeTagProcessor - [THYMELEAF][pool-2-thread-1][karate-feature.html] Deprecated attribute {th:include,data-th-include} found in template karate-feature.html, line 74, col 16. Please use {th:insert,data-th-insert} instead, this deprecated attribute will be removed in future versions of Thymeleaf.
10:45:44.890 [pool-2-thread-1] WARN  o.t.s.p.AbstractStandardFragmentInsertionTagProcessor - [THYMELEAF][pool-2-thread-1][karate-feature.html] Deprecated unwrapped fragment expression "karate-step.html" found in template karate-feature.html, line 74, col 16. Please use the complete syntax of fragment expressions instead ("~{karate-step.html}"). The old, unwrapped syntax for fragment expressions will be removed in future versions of Thymeleaf.
10:45:44.914 [pool-2-thread-1] WARN  o.t.s.p.StandardIncludeTagProcessor - [THYMELEAF][pool-2-thread-1][karate-feature.html] Deprecated attribute {th:include,data-th-include} found in template karate-feature.html, line 74, col 16. Please use {th:insert,data-th-insert} instead, this deprecated attribute will be removed in future versions of Thymeleaf.
10:45:44.914 [pool-2-thread-1] WARN  o.t.s.p.AbstractStandardFragmentInsertionTagProcessor - [THYMELEAF][pool-2-thread-1][karate-feature.html] Deprecated unwrapped fragment expression "karate-step.html" found in template karate-feature.html, line 74, col 16. Please use the complete syntax of fragment expressions instead ("~{karate-step.html}"). The old, unwrapped syntax for fragment expressions will be removed in future versions of Thymeleaf.
```

Answer (score 2):

The specific issue you refer to will be fixed in 1.4.1, refer PRs [#2372](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/pull/2372) and [#2368](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/pull/2368)